# mysqlclient installation error in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a django with mysql app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, so `mysqlclient` library is needed. `mysqlclient` needs `python3-devel` and `mysql-devel` package to be installed, so I have the custom config file for it `01_packages.config`:

```
packages: 
  yum:
    python3-devel: []
    mysql-devel: []
```

Deployment fails and the log file `/var/log/cfn-init.log` (mentioned in Beanstalk logs) shows the error:

```
2020-05-31 02:17:37,565 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2020-05-31 02:17:37,572 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2020-05-31 02:17:37,575 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2020-05-31 02:17:37,579 [INFO] Running config prebuild_0_doyouknow
2020-05-31 02:17:41,831 [ERROR] mysql-devel is not available to be installed
2020-05-31 02:17:41,831 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of prebuild_0_doyouknow: Yum does no
t have mysql-devel available for installation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 542, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 229, in build
    changes['packages'][manager] = CloudFormationCarpenter._packageTools[manager]().apply(packages,
 self._auth_config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/rpm_tools.py", line 74, in apply
    raise ToolError("Yum does not have %s available for installation" % pkg_spec)
ToolError: Yum does not have mysql-devel available for installation
2020-05-31 02:17:41,834 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
```

However, I tried to install it manually on my Ec2 instance through `yum install mysql-devel` and it is installed successfully.

My python version is 3.7 and my `requirements.txt` file content is:

```
asgiref==3.2.7
Django==3.0.5
django-cors-headers==3.2.1
django-dotenv==1.4.2
django-social-share==1.4.0
mysqlclient==1.4.6
numpy==1.18.4
pandas==1.0.3
Pillow==7.1.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
xlrd==1.2.0
```

Comment: is there more in your cfn-init.log log to show how yum is invoked?

Comment: @danblack unfortunately no, it is just repeating the same part.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Solved!** I have replaced `mysql-devel` with `mariadb-devel` and it worked successfully, then I was able to install `mysqlcient` library.

My new `01_packages.config`:

```
packages: 
  yum:
    python3-devel: []
    mariadb-devel: []
```

I don't know the root cause of it, but I did so as I noticed that the manual installation of `mysql-devel` through `yum install mysql-devel` is actually installing `mariadb-devel` !

Here is my ec2 instance release details. Maybe it is because of the new Amazon Linux Release 2.

```
$ cat /etc/*-release*
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)
cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2
```

Comment: I did some investigation, and indeed it seems that the old Amazon Linux AMI for Elastic Beanstalk included mysql, but the Amazon Linux 2 AMI for Elastic Beanstalk does not.

So when upgrading from the old platform to the new one, it seems one has to add the correct packages to a config file, as Yasser said. I only needed mariadb-devel.

Comment: @Yasser Mohsen, That was it.

Answer (score 7):

**Follow-up to this for 2023 for the new Linux Platforms:**

mariadb-devel is no longer the name of the package. Instead, use

```
packages:  
  yum:  
    python3-devel: []
    mariadb105-devel.x86_64: []
```

For future versions, you can check for what packages you can install by:

1. Connecting to your EC2 instance that has EB is using via Session Manager.
2. Run `yum list available`
3. Search for variations of the mariadb-devel (or even mysql-devel if they bring that back).

Comment: Thank you so so much, I have been searching for this for 2-3 days.

Comment: Not sure why you picked the devel version, it has mariadb105.x86_64 version as well.

Comment: Used the devel version to be consistent with the original posting. Other version could work too