# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: can't install mysqlclient

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am going through the [adding database](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-rds.html) to elastic beanstalk python documentation but following the steps leads to the following error

```
2023/05/07 14:06:36.847596 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [InstallDependency]. Stop running the command. Error: fail to install dependencies with requirements.txt file with error Command /bin/sh -c /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      /bin/sh: line 1: mysql_config: command not found
      /bin/sh: line 1: mariadb_config: command not found
      /bin/sh: line 1: mysql_config: command not found
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-7hpz1pvs/mysqlclient_f18de82744fa43e9b3b8706c3e581791/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
          metadata, options = get_config()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-install-7hpz1pvs/mysqlclient_f18de82744fa43e9b3b8706c3e581791/setup_posix.py", line 70, in get_config
          libs = mysql_config("libs")
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-install-7hpz1pvs/mysqlclient_f18de82744fa43e9b3b8706c3e581791/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
          raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
      OSError: mysql_config not found
      mysql_config --version
      mariadb_config --version
      mysql_config --libs
      [end of output]
```

I did some digging and came to the conclusion that mysql or mariadb is not installed to the ec2 instance. So I started browsing [the available packages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/release-notes/all-packages-al2023-20230501.html) for the Amazon Linux 2023 AMI since my ec2 is running that version and modified my config in `.ebextensions` folder to look like this:

```yaml
packages:
  yum:
    mysql-selinux: []
    mariadb105: []
    mariadb-connector-c: []
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
  02_createsuperuser:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py createsuperuser --noinput --username aradipatrik2 --email ap@gmail.com"
    leader_only: true
  03_save_data_to_db:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py save_data_to_db"
    leader_only: true
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: env_info.settings
```

The packages install successfully but I still get the same exact error. When I ssh into the ec2 device to install mysql or mariadb manually the terminal tells me:

> Changes made via SSH
> WILL BE LOST if the instance is replaced by auto-scaling

*So my question is*:
How can I install mysql or mariadb onto the ec2 instance when deploying the application using elastic beanstalk, so I can have `mysqlclient==2.0.3` inside my `requirements.txt`

My `requirements.txt`

```
asgiref==3.6.0
branca==0.6.0
certifi==2022.12.7
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
Django==4.2.1
folium==0.14.0
idna==3.4
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
numpy==1.24.3
python-dotenv==1.0.0
requests==2.29.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
tzdata==2023.3
urllib3==1.26.15
mysqlclient==2.0.3
```

edit: Received feedback to install mariadb package with a name ending in -dev or -devel but there's no such package listed at [the available packages list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/release-notes/all-packages-al2023-20230501.html) for the Amazon Linux 2023 AMI any further pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: You likely need a MySQL or mariadb package with a name ending in -dev or -devel

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/release-notes/all-packages-al2023-20230501.html
This supposed to be the list of all available packages for the os of my ec2 instance. I can't find any such package there. Could you please share where can I discover these packages and how to install them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some trial and error I ended up modifying my config file to start with this, which solved my issue

```yaml
packages:
  yum:
    mariadb105-devel: []
```

I found the package completely by chance. If someone know how to discover these for the future please do tell me

Comment: Thank you! Just spent a day trying to get flask_mysqldb to play nice in a Flask app in ELB. This did the trick.

Comment: They should really update their documentation. It's pretty bad that following their documentation exactly step-by-step will yield to hard to track down errors...

Comment: wow, this is very obscure but worked like a charm. great find!

Comment: you can find newly named packages by ssh to al2023 instance and type yum search.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2024**: For me the currently available packages are

- mariadb-devel.x86_64 : Files for development of MariaDB/MySQL
  applications
- mariadb.x86_64 : A community developed branch of MySQL