# Cannot install mysqlclient on Elastic BeanStalk Instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mysql-python

How can I get pip to install mysqlclient in Amazon Linux 2/Python 3.8 instance?

I am deploying a Django application to Elastic Bean Stalk. While the deployment process is running `pip install -r requirements.txt`, it fails and I get this error on eb-engine.log.

```
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [22 lines of output]
      Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Trying pkg-config --exists mariadb
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mariadb' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        ...
        File "<string>", line 154, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 48, in get_config_posix
        File "<string>", line 27, in find_package_name
      Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name.
      Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
enter code here
```

I know it has to do with having mysqlclient package installed. So, I have these packages defined in my .ebextension package file. I have found multiple answers to suggest specifying `mariadb-devel.x86_64`, `mariadb-devel`, `mariadb-server`, etc,. as packages to install to fix the error, however even with the packages installed, I still run into the above error.

I also install this packages by running these platform prebuild hooks commands, but still does not fix the problem.

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch.rpm
sudo yum localinstall mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch.rpm
```

Have the package to install `mysqlclinet` in Amazon linux 2 changed recently as suggested [in these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62111066/mysqlclient-installation-error-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk) (answers do not work for me)? Am I specifying the wrong packages?

```
packages: 
    yum:
        python3-devel: [] 
        MySQL-python: []
        mariadb-devel.x86_64: []
        mariadb-server: []
        gcc: [] 
        gawk: []
        polkit: []
        gcc-c++: []
        make: []
        pkgconfig: []
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below packages, and it should work fine for Amazon Linux 2023

```
packages:
  yum:
    python3-devel: []
    mariadb105-devel.x86_64: []
```